# Shiny mainPanel Output Blank; RStudio viewer updates instead

Tags: r, shiny

When I run my shiny app, the mainPanel does not render the process_map image. However, in the RStudio Viewer, the image renders. I have researched this issue and it feels like the problem is with the process_map() call, as I am not having these problems with other calls (simple ggplot/plot). I do not believe outputPlot/renderPlot is appropriate for the process_map() function. However, I am unable to determine the correct call, or a functional work around.

Here is a reproducible example. Thanks in advance for your expertise.

```
#POTENTIAL PACKAGE REQUIREMENTS
#install.packages("bupaR")
#install.packages("edeaR")
#install.packages("eventdataR")
#install.packages("processmapR")
#install.packages("processmonitR")
#install.packages("xesreadR")
#install.packages("petrinetR")


library(bupaR)
library(shiny)

#Create a data frame
key<-rep("DISCHARGEDATE", 5)
time<-seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-20 12:07:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
by="min",length.out = 5)
patient<-seq(1,5)

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(key=as.character(key),time=as.character(time),
patient=as.character(patient)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$time<- as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#create a simple log
s.Log<-bupaR::simple_eventlog(eventlog=df, 
                              case_id="patient",
                              activity_id="key",
                              timestamp="time") 
#shiny
ui <- fluidPage(

mainPanel(
         plotOutput("process_map")
      )
   )

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$process_map <- renderPlot({

     process_map(s.Log)

   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`process_map` gives the output of class `grViz`. Hence you have to use `grVizOutput` in the `ui` and `renderGrViz` in the `server` from the `DiagrammeR` package. I have modified your code as follows which gives process_map image.

```
   library(bupaR)
   library(shiny)
   library(DiagrammeR)
   #Create a data frame
   key<-rep("DISCHARGEDATE", 5)
   time<-seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-20 12:07:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
             by="min",length.out = 5)
   patient<-seq(1,5)

   df<-as.data.frame(cbind(key=as.character(key),time=as.character(time),
                           patient=as.character(patient)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   df$time<- as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

   #create a simple log
   s.Log<-bupaR::simple_eventlog(eventlog=df, 
                                 case_id="patient",
                                 activity_id="key",
                                 timestamp="time") 
   #shiny
   ui <- fluidPage(

     mainPanel(
       #plotOutput("process_map")
       grVizOutput("process_map")
     )
   )

   server <- function(input, output) {

     output$process_map <- renderGrViz({

       process_map(s.Log)

     })
   }

   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Ms. Bista. Much Obliged. Can you please let me know how you knew process_map gives the output of grViz? Just curious, in the case I ever run into an issue with output classes again. Regardless, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The function `class` gives you the type of object. In your case if you `class( process_map(s.Log)` you will get `grViz` and `htmlwidgets` as its type.

Comment: Hi SBista, I wish to know, is there a way such that I can make the diagram dynamic such that when clicked on an arc, it displays the corresponding cases in second table.

Comment: Do you mean you want tooltip? If so you can look into package [visNetwork](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visNetwork/vignettes/Introduction-to-visNetwork.html)