# Process Mining using ggplot2 and plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

the script below creates a process map diagram using standard built in patients data. I wish to customize the plot furthur using ggplot2 and plotly such that I can create a dynamic process diagram which is interactive. I am not getting, how to put ggplot2 in the commands below.  Thank you and please help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bupaR)
library(edeaR)
library(eventdataR)
library(processmapR)
library(processmonitR)
library(xesreadR)
library(ggplot2)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(plotly)

patients %>% process_map()
```

Comment: I don't think so you can use plotly or ggplot here because the output is `grviz` object, drwan using `viz.js`

Comment: `> class(process_map(patients))
[1] "grViz"      "htmlwidget"`

Comment: Thank you so much for replying Hardik, I too am struggling with this issue, I need to make the plot dynamic like how ggplotly is. Do you know any other ways as to how we can create the process map in the link that I'll attach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602433/creating-process-map-diagrams-using-different-packages-in-r

Comment: have you looked at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46480114/shiny-mainpanel-output-blank-rstudio-viewer-updates-instead/46482163#46482163

Comment: Also check here - https://www.r-bloggers.com/bupar-business-process-analysis-with-r/

Comment: Thanks but I have implemented that functionality in R shiny, see, the diagram has been created using diagrammeR, and needs to be made dynamic. Second link also done Sir. As you make the ggplot2 plot dynamic using ggplotly, I too wish to make the DiagrammeR plot dynamic.

Comment: you might have noticed one thing: your plots open in `viewer` not in plot. I doubt this will get converted to `plot` in rstudio, because it is using some javascript to create the plot

Comment: This plot comes in R shiny using renderDiagrammeR and grvizOutput, I have have done this also. I have to make the plot dynamic as in I should click on the arcs and perform onclick operations.

Comment: check this - https://github.com/rich-iannone/DiagrammeR/issues/126

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156255/discussion-between-ashmin-kaul-and-hardik-gupta).